# categorizing data of different formats with in same datatype

Tags: apex, formula-field, regular-expressions, design-patterns

I am trying  to achieve a strange case where i can see rows of different formats of data in an object .
Eg if i select phone number field on account, i need to get view of all the records which are stored in database having different formats.

Any idea how to achieve this would be of great help to me.

Comment: I would try to get all accounts with a batch job and check patter of each phone field.

Comment: you could also create several boolean formula fields, each testing for a specific pattern (assuming a finite set of possible patterns). Then you can easily do reports on which records meet pattern X vs pattern Y

Comment: crop1645, I tired the redex &patternmatching in salesforce for checking the type of data entered. how ever my main objective was to determine an mechanism to scan the select field of an object , and then all the different format present should be listed.